# control relays using 74hc595(shiftout)

Tags: arduino

**I want to use 7h4c595(8 IOs) to control 8 relays.**

**I tried using 0b00000000**, It's working fine.

but I don't know **how to concat switches values into this kind of binary**.

almost 0 knowledge about this. sorry

**I know the code below is not right**, but it seems working.

**problem**: 74hc595's q0 is controling the 2nd relay, not the 1st.

and q1 is controling 3rd relay.

It should be like q0->1st, q1-> 2nd, and so on.

**sorry for bothering you.**

[image]

[code]

```
uint8_t switch0=0;// 0 = off
uint8_t switch1=1;// 1 = on
etc...
uint8_t switch7=1;//1-7 on

setup(){
    etc...
}
loop(){
    if(digitalWrite(btn1)==HIGH){
        switch0=1;//on
        switch1=0;//off
        etc...//1-7 off
    }
    //unit8_t sw=0b10000000; //turn 1st relay on when btn1 pressed
    uint8_t sw={switch0,switch1,....,switch7};
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
        shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, i);   
        digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are asking in the wrong forum. A wiring diagram could be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the tip,wiring diagram now added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go in similar way how are the pins defined in avr/io.h

```
constexpr uint8_t RELAY0 = 0;
constexpr uint8_t RELAY1 = 1;
// ...
constexpr uint8_t RELAY7 = 7;


loop() {
  uint8_t data = (switch0 << RELAY0) | (switch1 << RELAY1) | /* ... |*/ (switch7 << RELAY7);

  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, data);   
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);

  delay(200); // or more
}
```

Or you can use single byte (uint8_t) for storing all switches at once. As a bonus you can send it over shiftOut directly.

```
uint8_t allSwitches = 0; // all relays disabled 

// turning relay x on (somewhere inside of function):
allSwitches |= _BV(x); // where x is number between 0 and 7 including

// turning relay x off:
allSwitches &= ~_BV(x);

// but you can set some of them and reset others in single step:
allSwitches = _BV(0) | _BV(5) | _BV(7);  // turns on relay 0, 5 and 7, rest will be turned off
```

Comment: thanks! how to search? your code syntax, I want to learn it from begining. :D

Comment: @xtr3mz Well, for example here: [Bit manipulation (AKA "Programming 101")](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-c-bit-manipulation-aka-programming-101?page=all)